# Ignore Bearer Token Validation for specific Urls in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2

I am configuring a micro service as a resource server which uses a JWK end point to validate the signature of the JWT Token.

I have setup the config to permit all `GET` requests in the service. All other requests are secured based on the scope and role. Here is the config that I am using.

```
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
class SecurityConfig : WebFluxConfigurer {

    @Bean
    fun authenticationEntryPoint(): ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint {
        return JwtBearerTokenServerAuthenticationEntryPoint()
    }

    @Bean
    fun accessDeniedHandler(): ServerAccessDeniedHandler {
        return JwtTokenAccessDeniedHandler()
    }

    @Bean
    fun springSecurityFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        http
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/docs/**", "/v2/api-docs/**", "/").permitAll()
            // Client should have the required scope to write to products
            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).hasAuthority(PRODUCT_WRITE_SCOPE)
            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT).hasAuthority(PRODUCT_WRITE_SCOPE)
            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE).hasAuthority(PRODUCT_WRITE_SCOPE)
            // health and info urls will be open(permitted to all) others will be checked for authorization
            .matchers(EndpointRequest.to(HealthEndpoint::class.java, InfoEndpoint::class.java)).permitAll()
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
            .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
            .jwt()
            .jwtAuthenticationConverter {
                jwtAuthenticationConverter(it)
            }

        return http.build()
    }

    private fun jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwt: Jwt): Mono<AbstractAuthenticationToken>? {
        val jwtAuthConverter = ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverter()
        jwtAuthConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter {
            val jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = JwtAuthoritiesConverter()
            val reactiveJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverterAdapter =
                ReactiveJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverterAdapter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter)
            reactiveJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverterAdapter.convert(it)
        }
        return jwtAuthConverter.convert(jwt)
    }

    companion object {
        private const val PRODUCT_WRITE_SCOPE = "SCOPE_product:write"
    }

}
```

The issue that I am facing is that if I send an expired token in the authorization header of a `GET` request, the token validation still happens and I get a token expired error.

Is there a way to change the configuration in such a way that the token validation only happens for some end points and is ignored for others?

Comment: why not just don't send the authorization header in all get requests?

Comment: I am sending the authorisation header in all the requests. That’s where the problem arises. If the token is expired, the GET request fails saying token is expired.

Comment: yes i do understand your problem, but as i said, a better solution would be to not send the token, when you don't want to be authorised.

Comment: @Toerktumlare That's  certainly an option but I think it might add a little more conditional checks in the client side implementation so want to avoid that. If there is no way to do it, that's what I will go with.

Comment: Think of it semantically, if you send an `Authorization` header you are telling the backend ”hi, here is my request and here is the header that proves who i am”. Now you want to send an auth header even though you dont want or should, and instead ignore it? To me that sounds like creating more problems for oneself. I cant see any obvious in spring that lets you do just that, and pretty sure spring agrees with me. If you dont whant to be authorized, then don send an authorization header.

Comment: Yes, I agree. However, I found an alternative incase it needs to be done this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did to solve the problem. You have an option to specify which paths the security config should apply to. Here is the code snippet that specifies that.

```
.securityMatcher {
                ServerWebExchangeMatchers.matchers(
                    ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**"),
                    ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/**"),
                    ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/**")
                ).matches(it)
            }
```

Here is the full config.

```
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
class SecurityConfig : WebFluxConfigurer {

    @Bean
    fun authenticationEntryPoint(): ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint {
        return JwtBearerTokenServerAuthenticationEntryPoint()
    }

    @Bean
    fun accessDeniedHandler(): ServerAccessDeniedHandler {
        return JwtTokenAccessDeniedHandler()
    }

    @Bean
    fun springSecurityFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        http
            .securityMatcher {
                ServerWebExchangeMatchers.matchers(
                    ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**"),
                    ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/**"),
                    ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/**")
                ).matches(it)
            }
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/docs/**", "/v2/api-docs/**", "/").permitAll()
            // Client should have the required scope to write to products
            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).hasAuthority(PRODUCT_WRITE_SCOPE)
            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT).hasAuthority(PRODUCT_WRITE_SCOPE)
            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE).hasAuthority(PRODUCT_WRITE_SCOPE)
            // health and info urls will be open(permitted to all) others will be checked for authorization
            .matchers(EndpointRequest.to(HealthEndpoint::class.java, InfoEndpoint::class.java)).permitAll()
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
            .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
            .jwt()
            .jwtAuthenticationConverter {
                jwtAuthenticationConverter(it)
            }

        return http.build()
    }

    private fun jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwt: Jwt): Mono<AbstractAuthenticationToken>? {
        val jwtAuthConverter = ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverter()
        jwtAuthConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter {
            val jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = JwtAuthoritiesConverter()
            val reactiveJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverterAdapter =
                ReactiveJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverterAdapter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter)
            reactiveJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverterAdapter.convert(it)
        }
        return jwtAuthConverter.convert(jwt)
    }

    companion object {
        private const val PRODUCT_WRITE_SCOPE = "SCOPE_product:write"
    }

}
```

Comment: The negative side of this type of configuration is that you need to `opt-in` for security, whilst security should always be `opt-out`.